# How to use a mysql System Variables in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I've this in my where clause:

```
DATEDIFF(CONVERT_TZ(s.date, @@session.time_zone, '+00:00'), now()) between :range1 and :range2
```

but its giving me error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@'
```

So is it possible to use a system variable in hibernate query? How?